# How to convert comma delimited values to records?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL, I have a set of strings like...

```
Select 'AX', 'BC' from dual;
```

I need these strings as separate records as below.

Required Output:

```
Column1
---------------
AX

BC
```

Comment: What have you tried, have you read any documentation?

Comment: I tried connect by regexp, but its not working. Thanks.

Comment: Those aren't comma delimited values, just hard coded column values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can try this

```
with mydata as 
     (select q'[AX,BC]' mycol from dual)
       select regexp_substr(mycol, '[^,]+', 1, level) result from mydata
       connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(mycol, '[^,]+')) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be like this

```
with t as (Select 'AX' col1, 'BC' col2 from dual)
select col1 from t
union 
select col2 from t
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code. Hope this helps to achieve your results.

```
with table1 as
 (Select 'AX,BC' as data1 from dual)

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(data1, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) TXT
  FROM table1
CONNECT BY level <= length(regexp_replace(data1, '[^,]+')) + 1;
```